# KotlinTest Multiple Beans

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, kotlintest

I would like to create Tests for a SpringBoot application. I am reading an [example](https://github.com/kotlintest/kotlintest/blob/master/kotlintest-samples/kotlintest-samples-spring/src/test/kotlin/io/kotlintest/spring/MyBean.kt) and I cannot understard what should I do when I have multiple `MyBean` to test. Should I create a new `Test` file? Should I `Autowire` all of my beans into one class?
What I exactly want to do is to test some `RestController` [classes](https://github.com/BILLyTheLiTTle/RCCar/tree/master/src/main/kotlin/car/server).

Comment: Do you mean you have multiple beans you want to test in the same test file?

Comment: If you are writing unit tests, it's better to make each of these their own test file.  Additionally, you can either inject each `RestController` by name eg `MyRestController`, or you can inject a `List<RestController>`, but I'm really not sure what a list of rest controllers gains you.